# Direct scrolling using Gtk::Viewport (gtkmm3)

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtkmm, gtkmm3

I have a custom container which provides scrolling functionality by embedding a `Gtk::Grid` inside a `Gtk::Viewport`. The scrolling part works perfectly except for one glitch. Whenever an on_size_allocate event occurs it causes the `property_value` of the `Gtk::Adjustment` to reset to 0 causing the scroll position to jump to the top. Since this could happen when any of the children emits a queue resize or even when the top level window loses focus the scroll position sort of never stays where it should. By overriding the container's `on_size_allocate` handler I confirmed that the `property_value` of `Gtk::Adjustment` resets when I call the base class's `on_size_allocate`. Below is my `on_size_allocate` handler.

```
001 void CScrollGrid::on_size_allocate(Gtk::Allocation &oAlloc)
002 {
003  {
004    double dValue = m_refAdjustment->get_value();
005
006    std::cout << "size allocate (before), value: " << dValue << "\n";
007
008    Gtk::Widget::on_size_allocate(oAlloc);
009
010    std::cout
011      << "size allocate (after), value: "
012      << m_refAdjustment->get_value()
013      << "\n";
014
015    // Update scroll
016    {
017      int nMinimum;
018      int nDummy;
019
020      if (Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL
021          == m_eOrientation)
022      {
023        m_oGrid.get_preferred_height(nMinimum,
024                                     nDummy);
025      } else
026      {
027        m_oGrid.get_preferred_width(nMinimum,
028                                    nDummy);
029      }
030
031      m_refAdjustment->set_upper(nMinimum);
032    }
033
034    m_refAdjustment->property_value().set_value(dValue);
035
036    std::cout
037      << "size allocate (before fit), value: "
038      << m_refAdjustment->get_value()
039      << "\n";
040
041    Fit();
042  }
043 }
```

The stream output is as below.

```
size allocate (before), value: 146
size allocate (after), value: 0
size allocate (before fit), value: 0
```

At line 006 the stream output prints the correct 'value'. By line 010 the 'value' is reset to 0. As you can see that I have tried to apply the backed up value at line 034 but surprisingly the stream output at line 036 still returns 0! Looking at `gtk_viewport_size_allocate` (gtk code) I couldn't see anything obvious that relates to resetting of the `Gtk::Adjustment`.

- What could cause the `Gtk::Adjustment::property_value` to stay stuck at 0 even after being set to a non-zero value?
- What is the mechanism by which a `Gtk::Viewport` resets it's `Gtk::Adjustment`s?
- How can I prevent the `Gtk::Adjustment::property_value` from being reset like what's happening here?

NOTE: I didn't use Gtk::ScrolledWindow because of the following reason. The 'rows' inside the scrolled area could be of different heights. Irrespective of that the visible region needs to show the first and last row in full without clipping. When this is not possible, the last row is omitted and the extra space is converted as padding distributed evenly between top and bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my mistake. Instead of calling the parent classes `on_size_allocate` I should have just called `set_allocation`. Also there is no need to update the `Gtk::Adjustment`'s upper limit, `Gtk::ViewPort` does it internally. Following code works just fine.

```
001 void CScrollGrid::on_size_allocate(Gtk::Allocation &oAlloc)
002 {
003     set_allocation(oAlloc);
004 
005     Fit();
006 }
```